# Random index entry in an array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I am trying to fill an array with the digit "1" to a random index!Can anyone help me please?Thank you in advance :)

---

```
    int[] array = new int[5]; //main array
    int[] tempArray = new int[array.length]; //temporary array
    boolean isThere;
    int randomIndex;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        isThere = false;
        randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * array.length);
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (tempArray[j] == randomIndex) {
                isThere = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isThere) {
            array[randomIndex] = 1;
            tempArray[i] = randomIndex;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\n" + array[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Please provide more detail.What is the problem in your code ? Any exception ?

Comment: FIlling an array at a random index doesn't make much sense, do you want to **insert** a value at a random index instead?

Comment: "do you want to insert a value at a random index instead?" Yes.. thats exactly what i want!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to fill an array in (specific) random order.

You can try this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    list.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
// now that the list has been shuffled.
for (Integer item:list){
    array[i] = 1;
}
```